# CD- and USB-less install of Linux Mint 14...from Haiku and/or BeOS

Tags: linux, boot, linux-mint, haiku, beos

I have a system that boots BeOS and Haiku nightly, and has a spare partition which I used to have PC-BSD booting on.  (I use Haiku's BootManager on .../master/raw.)  I want to try Linux Mint 14, but I don't have a spare USB stick and my drive only burns CDs and the Mint download was 800-900MB.

While the BSD partition was still marked as FreeBSD-type, I had used this (in Haiku) to copy the iso overtop of it:

```
dd if=/boot/home/Desktop/linuxmint-14-xfce-dvd-32bit.iso of=/dev/disk/ata/0/master/3 bs=1M oflag=direct
```

When I try to boot to it, the first thing it says is something about a missing or corrupt isolinux.bin, even though under Haiku I can mount the new partition and see that file just fine.  (It says it once and then looks like it tries to network boot--I'm not sure if that's Mint's bootloader trying that or my BIOS.)

I then tried using BeOS' DriveSetup to reinitialize the partition to FAT32 and copy over it again with the above `dd` command in Haiku (I would have used `dd` in BeOS but it didn't support `oflag`.)  Exact same result.

How can I get this working from just this system, without a USB stick nor burning anything?

Comment: Why don't you buy usb stick, they are very cheap and the easiest way.

Comment: Donations accepted...  :)

Comment: Isn't unetbootin working on harddrive partitions?

Comment: Don't think it runs on Haiku/BeOS though

Comment: My friend sucessfuly installed even windows 7 with unetbootin, all you need is iso to make bootable usb stick

Comment: But what did he prepare unetbootin on?

Comment: Im just amazed someone is using Haiku...

Comment: @Keltari, full time.  I currently tri-boot Haiku "stable" (as defined subjectively by me), Haiku nightly, and BeOS R5 Pro.  They're least fussy things I've found that boot quickly and run decently on my old hardware.